# Facebook module for Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, facebook, twitter

Could you recommend a Drupal module that provides similar features like http://drupal.org/project/twitter for Facebook?

Thanks

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/fbconnect ?

Answer (score 2):

The link I posted below will show you every available Facebook module there is for on drupal.org.

http://drupal.org/search/apachesolr_search/facebook?filters=type%3Aproject_project

Of all of them though, I'd probably recommend *http://drupal.org/project/fbconnect* and/or maybe *http://drupal.org/project/fbstatus*.

Hope that helps!  :)

Answer (score 0):

As per comparison in drupal modules like "Drupal for Facebook","Facebook Connect" and "Facebook OAuth"

[Facebook OAuth](https://www.drupal.org/project/fboauth) is the winner it is simple and flexible, and best of all, you don't need to learn Facebook's Javascript SDK to use it

See more at: http://www.grasmash.com/article/connecting-facebook-drupal-easy-way#sthash.JhLNJENw.dpuf